# Algorithm for Interpreting For Uniform Bernoulli Sequence as Non-Uniform

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a large, uniformly distributed sequence of binary digits (P(1) = P(0)) and I need to interpret this sequence of random bits as an **EQUAL** sized sequence of binary digits whose distribution is not uniform (i.e. P(1) != P(0)).

Specifically, I am looking for either of the following:

1.) an **INVERTIBLE** function F whose domain is equal to its range = the set of N bit binary sequences (i.e.  a function whose domain = range = {0,1}^N for some fixed N) **AND** with the property that the **function maps sequences of high entropy to ones of low entropy and vice versa as well as possible**

Ideas?

It is for compression; I will post more about this later

Answer (score 2):

Shannon proved that it's impossible to compress a uniform random binary string. Compression algorithms exploit non-uniformity in the input distribution.

Comment: Is this on AVERAGE or for any PARTICULAR such sequence. I am not trying to come up with magic compression; I am trying to create a completely worthless program that simply compresses a large, random, uniformly distributed binary sequence to win a prize.

Comment: I assume you're talking about this challenge: http://marknelson.us/2006/06/20/million-digit-challenge/ . The relevant definition of compression is Kolmogorov compression, and almost all strings are not Kolmogorov compressible.

Comment: I doubt the unavoidability of it becoming an unreadable mess. You just need to structure your code in a way that suits the language. That is of course true in every language, but Java is singled out for it, usually by people unwilling or unable to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole lot more high entropy sequences than low ones. If the function is both invertible and has domain equal to range, there's no way to do that mapping.

edit for your comment:

```
A = YourLargeSequence

f(0^N) = A
f(A) = 0^N
otherwise, f(x) = x
```

has all the properties you've asked for.  Domain = Range = {0,1}^N, it's inverse is itself, 0 has low entropy.  I'm guessing you've left out a requirement?

Comment: I understand that there are more high entropy sequences than low 
entropy ones, so I know that it is impossible to map every high 
entropy sequence to a low entropy one, so what I am really interested 
in is interpreting a PARTICULAR uniform bernoulli sequence as a non-
uniform one, so that I can solve a COMPRESSION challenge. The idea is 
as follows: 

I am not trying to invent magic compression; I am just trying to 
compress a SINGLE, PARTICULAR, large uniform bernoulli sequence. 

Is there any way to find such a function? Also, what literature can I 
read that is related to my question?

Comment: ---- about the shannon limit - ? Is this on AVERAGE or for any PARTICULAR such sequence. I am not trying to come up with magic compression; I am trying to create a completely worthless program that simply compresses a large, random, uniformly distributed binary sequence to win a prize. – user562688 12 mins ago